# How to understand Hot plugin mechanism for a USB in an Android stack?

Tags: usb, android

I want to know where I could get some material to study USB hot plug-in mechanism in Android Stack. I tried googling many a times, but din't find anything useful.

Comment: are you trying to understand when you dock it on a computer or when you connect a usb device to the phone/tablet?

Comment: @aking1012: Connecting USB into a tablet with Android stack

Comment: I can't put my finger on it at the moment but on: http://android.git.kernel.org/ I think it should be in platform/hardware or platform/external - probably external

Comment: @aking1012 is right, android uses a GNU/Linux kernel

Comment: @tmow Thanks - I was thinking they wanted everything in modules, but USB support is built into the android kernel itself.  Added the location of the relevant code in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Okay found it...on http://android.git.kernel.org it is located in kernel/linux-2.6.git/drivers/usb/